# Grub not appearing when booting as well not in the bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I recently installed a dual boot of ubuntu 22.04.1 and windows everything works fine until I select windows in the grub bootload. After I do so grub disappears when I try to boot it defaults to windows boot manager and in the bios, I can't see it there either. When I tried reinstalling ubuntu it worked fine but the problem still continued when I went into windows.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using. Grub is never in the BIOS. Please clarify by using EDIT and add info to the question.

Comment: Both Windows & Ubuntu will update UEFI settings to have its install first in boot order whenever major updates are run. Depending if UEFI or very old BIOS, the way to reset is different, but you only need to reset UEFI/BIOS with desired boot loader.Both installs must be in same boot mode, or both UEFI with most systems, now.

Answer (score 1):

I use a utility called Grub2Win to boot any of 3 OSes on my PC. It installs in Windows and offers very configurable options including what OS to boot by default after a user specified time has elapsed. After install it scans the drives and partitions and sets up a menu that you can rearrange. If you add or change an OS it can re-scan and keep up with changes.

Comment: Some people don't like this program. But I use it too to boot one of my 3 OS's. Some major Windows updates prioratize the default Windows loader again, but running this program and choose it as default boot loader again solves that problem. Very easy, just a question of clicking the appropiat box, and your back in bussiness again.